# Without using Spring ACL, implementing a method level security check based on "creator" of an entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, acl

Like many others have noted, the ACL seems like overkill for executing such a conceptually simple thing in a case like this.

I am looking for a simple implementation of the following scenario in Spring Security:

I have a method in a controller which handles a delete request for an event entity. I need the @PreAuthorize expression that will check to make sure that the ID of the user submitting the request matches the ID of the owner of the request. Perhaps through an Event.getOwner().getId() method.

How would this look? Thanks.

I'm thinking something like. The following method in the Event controller:

```
 @PreAuthorize("#event.getOwner().getId() == authentication.id")
 public void delete(@PathVariable("id") final Long id, @RequestBody final Event event) {
    repo.delete(id, event);
}
```

And if this is the correct use, where does #event come from? In other words, what is signified by the '#'? I ask because at this point we are in the controller, so, which Event is #event referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is not safe. It requires that the event information including owner is sent as request body in the delete request. With this the client can spoof the owner to be of the current user instead of the actual owner.

Assuming that `id` is the unique id of an event, I would suggest something like the following as a minimal solution:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
@PreAuthorize("@repo.getOwnerOfEvent(#id) == authentication.name")
public void delete(@PathVariable("id") final Long id) {
    repo.deleteEvent(id);
}
```

The above snippet requires a bean named "repo" that contains the method:

```java
/**
 * Returns the owner username of the event with the specified id.
 */
String getOwnerOfEvent(long id);
```

Comment: So essentially, the database layer is the definitive gatekeeper in your scenario, because there is no direct entry point for a client to spoof the eventOwnerID upon sending the request. Instead, the eventOwnerID is definitively checked ONLY by the dto repo. Correct?

Comment: Also, I'd like to ask you a second question since you've just given me a great solution. What is your opinion on building with a setup like you've suggested vs. use of a full on ACL system (which seems to be the standard textbook option, very scalable, but obviously may be complicated overkill for such a simple check that will only be authorized against 3 or 4 methods at most)?

Comment: @TylerDurden Yes, the important thing is to read the owner from the database. Regarding ACL:s you have pretty much already stated the pros and cons ...

Comment: Hey @holmis83 could you check out another quest I have on ACL implementation? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/q/43619171/7691083